# How to set Object's values as a type in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, object, types, jsdoc

I have an object like this :

```js
const logTypes = {
    debug: '35',
    log  : '37',
    info : '34',
    warn : '33',
    error: '31'
}; // Don't pay attention to the values, it's for a specific system.
```

And I want a function that takes one of the value in argument with JSDoc. 
I tried `@param {logTypes} logType` but it doesn't seem to be working.

What am I missing ?

Comment: `@param { keyof typeof logTypes}` ?

Comment: I'm getting an `Invalid type syntax` (using Webstorm).

Comment: I don't know much webstorm. Did you enable jsdoc in webstorm ?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question.  But if you want to describe a parametger which take one of log levels as an argument, it could be done as: `@param {'debug'|'log'|'info'|'warn'|'error'} logLevel`

Comment: @CedricGourville Yes it's enabled.

Comment: @rumata28 I want to make this but by putting only 1 option

Comment: Again, not sure I understood what you mean by " putting only 1 option".  You may `/** @typedef {'debug'|'log'|'info'|'warn'|'error'} LogLevel */` and then `@param {LogLevel}`

Comment: Looks like an `@enum` to me. Have you tried that?

Comment: `keyof` works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const logTypes = {
  debug: '35',
  log: '37',
  info: '34',
  warn: '33',
  error: '31',
};

/**
 * @type {( type: keyof typeof logTypes ) => void}
 */
const log = () => {};
```

[image]